# trigger create jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

i have a problem, i have this code

```
<ul id="lista" data-role="listview"  data-theme="b" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Players</li>
```

and this script

```
    $('#home').live('pageinit',function(){
      $.getJSON("prendivalori.php",function(result){
          var nome = result[1].NOME;
          var overall = result[1].OVERALL;
          $('#lista').append('<li data-corners="false" data-count-theme="f" data-icon="arrow-r" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-li-has-count"><a href="#valori"  class="ui-link-inherit data-transition="pop"><h1>'+nome+'</h1><p id="squadra" class= "ui-li-desc" ></p><span id= "" class="ui-li-count ui-btn-corner-all"><font id="number">'+overall+'</font></span></a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r"></span></li>').trigger('create');
          });

});
```

but when the page load the listview doesn't look with mobile style
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.trigger("create")` method is meant to initialize the widgets on your page, in this case you listview has already been initialized and what you want to do is refresh it (in reality this should probablly really be included in the `.trigger("create")` method) .

In order to refresh a listview you should use the listview's [refresh](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-methods.html) method

For example

```
 $('#lista').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Your welcome. You can accept an anwser by clicking the hollow check-mark to the left of the anwser.

Comment: i have also this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886689/transition-loading-message-jquery-mobile)  do you know something?