# Transition loading message in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, message, transition

I have a problem:
This is my script, and it is called on a click

```
$("#next").live("click", function() {
    $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
        text: 'loading',
        textVisible: true,
        theme: 'b',
        html: "" 
    });
    $('.giocatore').remove();
    var pagina = parseInt($('#home').attr('pagina'));
    $('#home').attr('pagina',pagina+1);
    $('#back').append('<a id="prev" data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">Prec</a>').trigger('create');
    caricalista();
});
```

It does something to my webpage. I want that during the time it does something, the page shows me a loading message or some transition like the "pop" when i pass from page to page in jquery mobile.

Now with my code the page display me the loading message but it remain also after the script is executed

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom event.

after you done with your work just trigger an announcement that it is done. Add this line to very last of your existing function:

```
$(document).trigger('customEvent');
```

now outside of the function make a subscription to that announcement:

```
$(document).on('customEvent', function () {
     // hide your loading message
});
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

how do you know when your code have finished doing something? you have to make an announcement with your code that something is executed. after that you just have to hide the loading message. try jQuery pubsub

watch this video. you'll get what you need

https://tutsplus.com/lesson/custom-events-and-the-observer-pattern/

Thanks

Comment: sorry but the video in not available, can you explane what you mean?